# Unable to send exact error messages from nodejs to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

In my nodejs application, I have set up some error handling but the exact error messages don't get sent to the browser as I have set them. Instead an error object is sent that does not contain the specific error message. However, the error messages can be printed out in the nodejs console but not sent to the browser. The front end is vuejs.

Here is my nodejs code.

```
//To sign up a new user
userRoutes.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        //Check if the user is already registered
        const registeredUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        if (registeredUser) {
            console.log("There is a user already") //Prints out in the node console
            throw new Error("This email is already registered") //Does not sent this message to the broswer
        }

        const user = new User(req.body)
        await user.save()
        sendWelcomeEmail(user.email, user.firstName)
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.status(201).send({ user, token })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e) //Prints out the error message in the node console
        res.status(400).send(e) //Sends a complex error object without the error message
    }
})
```

And below is the complex error object that gets sent to the browser:

```
{ "error": { "config": { "transformRequest": {}, "transformResponse": {}, "timeout": 0, "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN", "maxContentLength": -1, "headers": { "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" }, "baseURL": "http://localhost:3000", "method": "post", "url": "http://localhost:3000/users", "data": "{\"firstName\":\"Efosa\",\"lastName\":\"Humna\",\"email\":\"user@yahoo.com\",\"password\":\"uyewhwehwj\"}" }, "request": {}, "response": { "data": {}, "status": 500, "statusText": "Internal Server Error", "headers": { "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }, "config": { "transformRequest": {}, "transformResponse": {}, "timeout": 0, "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN", "maxContentLength": -1, "headers": { "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" }, "baseURL": "http://localhost:3000", "method": "post", "url": "http://localhost:3000/users", "data": "{\"firstName\":\"Efosa\",\"lastName\":\"Humna\",\"email\":\"user@yahoo.com\",\"password\":\"uyewhwehwj\"}" }, "request": {} } } }
```

Please can someone help me point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually executing the code in the catch block? The `error.response` part of the object you quoted says:
```"status": 500, "statusText": "Internal Server Error",```
which is status 500, not 400 as you try to throw

Comment: That's not a complex object being sent from the server. That's what an `axios` response looks like when the server response is a `4xx` or `5xx`. That said -- you're not sending back a JSON object, anyway. You're sending a plain HTML document.

Comment: Try using this `res.status(400).json({ error: e.message });`

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using axios for xhr with vue, then you should use rather json response:

```
res.status(400).json(e.message) //send error message
```

It is good habit to create a global middleware to handle all errors in a express app, so in a try/catch you send an error to middleware with as `next(err)` and then process it in an error middleware where can format error depending on a environment (for example in a development, send full stack trace of error and in production send only common message). `next` is a third parameter of a router callback function btw.

Comment: Thanks Richard. However, res.status(400).json(e.message) gives the same problem and using next(err) only continues the code execution after that line instead of sending the error to the middleware I have created. I placed the error middleware as the next argument after the async function in the userRoute. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You should create global middleware and place it as a last middleware in your app js, also keep in mind that error middleware must have 4 arguments (err, req, res, next). Can you provide some example code on git with reproduced bug?

Comment: Thanks Richard. res.status(400).send(e.message) has solved it for me. I also had to extract the error message at the front end using error.response.data.